# Prolog: find max value between some results of a query

Tags: prolog

I have the following rule:

```
compute_stats(A, B, C)
```

which returns, as you can see, three values each iteration:

- A is an integer;
- B is another one integer;
- C is a list.

I would like to ask you how can I find the result with the highest A (integer).

Example:

If I call

```
compute_stats(A, B, C).
```

I get as result something like

```
A = 1000,
B = 10,
C = ['example1', 'example2'];

A = 1200,
B = 3,
C = ['example3', 'example4'];

A = 800,
B = 7,
C = ['example5', 'example6'];
```

Now I need another one rule which gives me only

```
A = 1200,
B = 3,
C = ['example3', 'example4'];
```

because it has the max A.

I've tried a lot of different things but they seem not to work :(

Thank you in advice!

Comment: First suggestion: Rename your predicate to a name that describes it being a relation. `get` does not fit here. Who or what is `get`? It's an imperative, a command apt for imperative/command-oriented programming languages.

Comment: You are right. I'm new and still have to get into this kind of thinking!

Comment: So give it a better name. (As an edit at the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. One way is to take advantage of the fact that `setof/3` sorts its results.

```
 max_stats(MaxA, MaxB, MaxC) :-
     setof(A-B-C, get_stats(A,B,C), R),   % All results ordered by A (ascending)
     reverse(R, [MaxA-MaxB-MaxC|_]).      % Maximum results
```

Here, the `setof/3` collects, in ascending order, a list of "tuples" `A-B-C` that are all the results from `get_stats(A,B,C)`. Since you want the maximum value, we reverse the order of that result (with `reverse/2`), and take the first element of that list as the maximum. The ordering for terms of the form `A-B-C` will be ordered first according to the sort order of `A`, so the results will provide those for maximum `A`.

---

Per comments from @false, you might have multiple maximum results (that have the same value as maximum). One way to handle this is have `max_stats` have a list argument which represents a list of maximum results:

```
max_stats(MaxResults) :-
    setof(A-B-C, get_stats(A,B,C), R),       % All results ordered by A (ascending)
    reverse(R, DescendingList),
    all_max(DescendingList, MaxResults). % Maximum results

% all_max/2 assumes the first argument is in descending order
% and the second argument is the list of just the maximum values
% of the first list

all_max([X], [X]).
all_max([X, Y|_], [X]) :- X @> Y.
all_maxx([X, Y|T], [X|S]) :-
    equal_elements(X, Y),
    all_max([X|T], S).

equal_elements(X-_-_, X-_-_).
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly and the code is clean and simple!

Comment: OP asked for highest A. Not for highest A-B-C.

Comment: @false - OP asked for `A`, `B`, and `C` set that has the highest `A` (*...how can I find the result with the highest A*). Doesn't the `setof` sort of `A-B-C` achieve that as I describe (lightly) in my answer?

Comment: What if there is a maximal A but with different B and C? You take one instead of all of them.

Comment: @false that is true. I took the OP literally when they said *the* maximum.

Comment: Literally, OP said "because it has the max A." I cannot see how this excludes a situation where there are two solutions that both have "the max".

Comment: @false oh I'm not saying it is excluded. I'm just saying I made that initial assumption. Since I'm out shopping right now, I'm not in a good position to update my answer to be more comprehensive. Comments are tedious enough with the mobile app. :)